# How do i output a log in Android?

Tags: android, logging, output

I have seen like a million different log functions , like `log.i` , `log.v` , `log.d` .

I just want to output a simple string on the log some times in my code to see if everything is working ok for debugging.

What is the clean way to do that?

Comment: How about `debug` mode? No junk values in the log required. You can directly see the state of the objects, on the fly!

Comment: Use Log.d() method where d is Debug

Comment: Why does Log.d need 2 string arguments though?

Comment: one is for the tag, second for the message

Comment: Its clear from documentation itself http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#d%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: lol i will man , whats wrong with you? I cant even accept an answer yet.. need to wait some time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are different type of log.

I = Info

V = Verbose

D = Debug

E = Error

Example:

```
Log.d("tag","the string youd like");

Log.v("tag","the string youd like");

Log.e("tag","the string youd like");

Log.i("tag","the string youd like");
```

Comment: How is your answer different from the 4 that were given before that?

Answer (score 5):

You can use Log to track the logs in your application code.

Log API is for sending log output.

Generally, use the Log.v() Log.d() Log.i() Log.w() and Log.e() methods.

The **order in terms of verbosity(wordiness)**, from least to most is **ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, VERBOSE**. Otherwise more or less they are same.

Verbose should never be compiled into an application except during development.

Debug logs are compiled in but stripped at runtime.

Error, warning and info logs are always kept.

Answer (score 3):

example

```
String TAG = "value of i = ";

for(int i = 0; i<=10 i++)
{
  Log.i(TAG, i+"");
}
```

this will print the 10 numbers in your log.i `(info)`.

[image]

```
log.d
```

is for debug

```
log.e
```

is for error

and so on. here is a link to study more about [log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)

Answer (score 2):

When you change the letters after `log.` you are basically setting the severity of this log record:

```
I => Info
V => Verbose
D => Debug
E => Error
```

Take a look at this picture for all the different kinds of log records:

[image]

So use `.d` for simple debugging records like this:

```
Log.d (TAG, "the message you want to out put");
```

While I always set the `TAG` at the begging of the class like this:

```
static final String TAG = YouCurrentActivity.class.getSimpleName();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Log.d("tag","the string youd like");
```

log.d is for the debug list of LogCat

Answer (score 2):

@donparalias great question

The **Most easiest way:**

```
 public static final String LOG_TAG = "Facebook";


 public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) 
{
    Log.i(Facebook.LOG_TAG, "LoginListener onFacebookError " + error);

}
```

You can use one or all of these:

```
Log.d("tag","string");  ::  Debug

Log.v("tag","string");  ::  Verbose

Log.e("tag","string");  ::  Error

Log.i("tag","string");  ::  Info
```